# Accessing/browse remote files

Tags: c#, web-services

I am currently trying to work on a project in c# in which I want to access/browse the remote drives of a system like a local drive , can anyone help.
thanks

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Show your work and tell us what do you achieve..

Comment: thanks for your response but i have found out my mistake and its done now.... thanks again for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using "Map a network drive" option in Windows Explorer? it works exactly like u have described, and it doesn't need to use webservice (from the tags u have chosen for the question). 
you can programatically map a network drive using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90143/Mapping-Network-Drive-using-C

Comment: thanks ....i will surely give it a try